# It seems like I'm not passing pointers of objects correctly, but why?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am working on using pointers of objects and to be able to use their memory address to pass-over and retrieve information.

My program only passes the title of the book and no other information and I'm not sure why.

How to make that program to store and retrieve information correctly? I am using pointers to pass the values, should I change something in other than main function?

This is my main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    Author *pAuthor = new Author("John", "Doe");
    Publisher *pPublisher = new Publisher("Wrox", "10475 Crosspoint Blvd.", "Indianapolis");
    Book *pBook = new Book("Memory Management", pAuthor, pPublisher, 39.99);

    cout << pBook->getBookInfo() << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
};
```

book.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

Book::Book()
{
}

Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    this->title = title;
    this->price = price;
}

Book::~Book()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing pAuther and pPublisher to the Book constructor, but not doing anything with them.

Answer (score 2):

```
Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    this->title = title;
    this->price = price;
}
```

Here you're passing the pointers but not using them.

Comment: Ok, this is true. Do you have some advice how to use my pointer to fill out all overloads of Publisher constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can create two properties or fields to store the pointers that you are passing to the constructor and then you can use them where you need in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your book() constructor needs to call setAuthorName and setPublisher functions with data from pAuthor and pPublisher.